# Minecraft pocket on Hudl

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son has been playing Minecraft pocket version on his Hudl for a few weeks now, but he is saying that for some reason the arrows are now doing the opposite to what they should. When he presses the down arrow it goes up, left arrow goes right and so on. Don't know if he's changed something but it is causing us all a headache. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did he set the speed to -1? That causes the controls to become flipped. Try entering `speed 1` and see if that fixes it.